# Dynamically set 'float:left' on the DOM node will not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I create two DOM nodes elemA and elemB, and append them to the container node, before that, I set float style on elemA and elemB use js code, it turns out not working; at the other hand, if I remove `elemA.style['float'] = 'left'` and `elemB.style['float'] = 'left'`, and use css to set float, it works, I can not figure out why?

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var elemA = document.createElement('div');
var elemB = document.createElement('div');

elemA.className='elem-a';
elemA.style['float'] = 'left';
elemA.style['width'] = '45px';
elemA.style['height'] = '75px';
elemA.style['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
elemA.innerHTML = 'A';

elemB.className='elem-b'
elemB.style['float'] = 'left';
elemB.style['width'] = '45px';
elemB.style['height'] = '75px';
elemB.style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue';
elemB.style['marginLeft'] = '20px';
elemB.innerHTML = 'B';

container.appendChild(elemA);
container.appendChild(elemB);
```

```css
.elem-a {
  float: left;
}

.elem-b {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;">
</div>
```

Comment: IE8 is a Year 2009 product... let it fade out.

Comment: "After Jan. 12, 2016, only the most recent version of Internet Explorer available for a supported operating system will receive technical support and security updates," http://www.techtimes.com/articles/12722/20140811/17-months-until-ie8-support-ends.htm

Answer (score 2):

As said in Comment about IE8 you should work with modern browser

IE expect `styleFloat` property whereas other browser use `cssFloat` so you should use both in your Code for support IE as you can see I have commented out in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"  content="IT=edge,chrome=IE8">

    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var container = document.querySelector('#container');
        var elemA = document.createElement('div');
        var elemB = document.createElement('div');

        elemA.className='elem-a';
        elemA.style.styleFloat = 'left';//For IE
        elemA.style['float'] = 'left';
        elemA.style['width'] = '45px';
        elemA.style['height'] = '75px';
        elemA.style['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
        elemA.style['display']='block';
        elemA.innerHTML = 'A';

        elemB.className='elem-b'
        elemB.style.styleFloat = 'left';//For IE
        elemB.style['float'] = 'left';
        elemB.style['width'] = '45px';
        elemB.style['height'] = '75px';
        elemB.style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue';
        elemB.style['marginLeft'] = '20px';
        elemB.style['display']='block';
        elemB.innerHTML = 'B';

        container.appendChild(elemA);
        container.appendChild(elemB);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, it is what I need.